# Adding spark-r job to dataproc workflow template

Tags: google-cloud-platform, workflow, google-cloud-dataproc

I've tried to add a `spark-r` job step to my workflow template in two different ways.

Using a gcloud command:

```sh
gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates add-job spark-r gs://path/to/script.R \
    --step-id=<stepid> --workflow-template=<templateid>
```

Or by importing a YAML definition:

```
jobs:
- sparkRJob:
    mainRFileUri: gs://path/to/script.R
  stepId: <stepid>
placement:
  managedCluster:
    clusterName: cluster-sparkr
    config:
      gceClusterConfig:
        zoneUri: europe-west4-b
      masterConfig:
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-4
      workerConfig:
        machineTypeUri: n1-standard-4
        numInstances: 4
```

However both ways result in the following error:

> INVALID_ARGUMENT: Job "" must provide a job definition

Which leaves me slightly confused as to what exactly am I missing.

Answer (score 1):

I have tested your YAML definition and it worked for me with command:

```sh
gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates instantiate-from-file --file <definition.yaml>
```

Also, workflow template with Spark R job successfully created using gcloud commands:

```sh
gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates create my-test-wf-01
gcloud beta dataproc workflow-templates add-job spark-r gs://path/to/script.R \
    --step-id=my-test-step-id --workflow-template=my-test-wf-01
```

Output of the 2nd command above:

```
createTime: '2019-04-15T16:49:06.346Z'
id: my-test-wf-01
jobs:
- sparkRJob:
    mainRFileUri: gs://path/to/script.R
  stepId: my-test-step-id
```

Comment: I still get the same error message if I try to create this workflow.

Comment: I have added to my answer commands that worked for me. May you share full commands that you use to create workflow template?

Comment: What `gcloud` version do you use? Try to update to latest one.

Comment: On my local computer:
```Google Cloud SDK 241.0.0, 
beta 2019.02.22, 
bq 2.0.43, 
core 2019.04.02, 
gsutil 4.38```

I've also tried from the Active Cloud Shell on GCP but no dice either.

Comment: No more edits available on the previous comment :)

Gcloud should be the latest I think. I updated yesterday.

I'm not sure about the formatting of your second command. Is that valid? Anyway, the commands you wrote are basically the same that I tried.

Comment: I'm not sure why you are asking if commands are valid, but two commands is just a first 3 lines of the block (both commands start from `$`), further is an output after successful execution of the 2nd `gcloud` command. Updated answer to make it clearer.